# Student applicant / student visa to work visa transition?

Tags: germany

Suppose I came to Germany on a student applicant visa to write some exams and suppose it doesn't work out as planned, then would it be allowed to get the aufenthaltstitel later based on me being employed under a company as apprentice?

Comment: As I understand it, this *may* be granted at the discretion of the authorities. There is no right to get approved. It must be an apprenticeship in a recognized skilled trade.